# Wordpress wp_enqueue_script cdn itegrity/crossorigin?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, integrity

Need help to understand better how to add itegrity/crossorigin through wordpress wp_enqueue_script and wp_enqueue_style?

Not sure is it possible, but as far the tutorials and pages I have found, none of them include the two in the wp_enqueue_script.

For example bootstrap 4 alpha 6.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And wordpress wp_enqueue_script would look then:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap4-alpha6-js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '101', true );
```

Is there a way to add integrity and crossorigin to wp_enqueue_script?
If not, what would be the work arounds?